# SSIS package error in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, package

How to resole this error?

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:06:01
>   AM  Error: 2016-08-30 10:06:02.76     Code: 0xC0209303     Source:
>   Package Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"     Description:
>   The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not
>   registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in
>   32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154 
>   Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2016-08-30
>   10:06:02.76     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task Excel
>   Source [2]     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2016-08-30
>   10:06:02.76     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Excel Source failed validation and
>   returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2016-08-30
>   10:06:02.76     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed
>   validation.  End Error  Error: 2016-08-30 10:06:02.77     Code:
>   0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were
>   errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:06:01 AM 
>   Finished: 10:06:02 AM  Elapsed:  1.704 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

Answer (score 3):

Your trying to us a 64 bit driver when one is not present. You can install the 64 bit driver or assuming you already have the 32 bit driver installed force it to use a 32 bit runtime. Below is a screenshot of an sql agent job where this setting can be found.

[image]

Comment: this option is not availabe in sql server 2012

Comment: This option is available in SQL 2012. I updated my screenshot with one from SSMS 2012. The other was from an older version.

Comment: Please check all the options before saying it is not available. Agent>Job Step> Configuration Tab> Advanced

Comment: sorry.It is available .now it is working fine .Thank You so much

Answer (score 2):

Here 64bit driver is not installed, either install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

or run it on 32 bit in the debug/run settings

Comment: sql server 2012 not available that option to run in 32 bit mode.so if i want to install i have to uninstall existing one??

Comment: You can run by applying the setting in SQL Server agent job 'run in 32 bit mode' setting